# function inside coroutine scope is not cancelled

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to grasp coroutines. I have an expectation that this code shouldn't print anything. However, it prints "work done" so cancellation didn't do a thing. How is it so?

```
 suspend fun foo() = coroutineScope {
        launch { doSomeWork() }
    }

    suspend fun doSomeWork() {
        delay(10000)
        println("Work done")
    }


    suspend fun main() {
        val fooResult = foo()
        fooResult.cancel()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. The main coroutine suspends on "coroutineScope" call, that's why